# modeling issue with field with 4 values (1 or more)

Tags: mysql, sql

lets say I have an account object in my application, which currently represented as:

```
CREATE TABLE Account (
    accountId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (accountId)
);
```

Now, Account object need to also have Solution field...and Status have 4 different possible values:

Solution1, Solution2, Solution3, Solution4

What would be the right way to represent it in the database?

Account can have few statuses, and status can have few accounts...

So at first I thought create in the db table of Solutions and than have another table to hold the relationship, but its seems too complicated for a field that have only 4 possible values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a junction table to represent the relationships between accounts and solutions:

```
CREATE TABLE account_solution (
    accountId int NOT NULL,
    solutionId int NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (accountId, solutionId)
)
```

For your solution table, since there are only 4 values, you might be able to take advantage of MySQL's enum type, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE solution
    solutionId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    status ENUM('Solution1', 'Solution2', 'Solution3', 'Solution4')
);
```

Comment: wanted to use the enum, but I think you cannot have multiple selected per one field...@Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: cause account can have multiple solutions

Comment: @JohnBigs Maybe you missed the point of my answer.  The many-to-many relationship is represented within the junction table.  A given record in the `solution` table only corresponds to a single status.

Comment: If you have further questions, or you think that I missed something else, then drop another comment here.

Comment: i didnt miss it, i accepted the junction solution. it's just you also suggested another option of using enum, but in mysql enum is a sigle value and I need multiple

Comment: @JohnBigs A MySQL enum is just a way to cut back on storage usage.  Instead of storing `Solution1`, `Solution2`, etc. in a column, MySQL will store an index number of each solution value, which maps to a fixed location containing the actual string value.

Comment: Didn't get why you need solution table, according to this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html 
" The strings you specify as input values are automatically encoded as numbers. "
"1 or 2 bytes, depending on the number of enumeration values (65,535 values maximum)"

Comment: also, if Solution only have name, why wont I just stay with account_solution and instead of solutionId I will put solutionName and thats it? this way i dont need Solution table at all @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @JohnBigs Because if you did that, then your data would no longer be normalized.  If you were to add another field associated with a solution, then you would be repeating data.

Comment: Thank you so much for the knowledge, appreciate it, I needed that. But are there some cases when you will consider to do this cause it will make more sense considering your application structure and the data it will be represented? Also since the solution table have one field?

Comment: If the solutions table doesn't have _any_ fields, then in theory you'd only need the junction table.  Otherwise, you should use a third table for the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set [Mysql SET type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html)

```
CREATE TABLE Account (
    accountId int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    status set('Solution1','Solution2','Solution3','Solution4') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (accountId)
);
```

And if you want to select a specific status

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `Account` 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(  'Solution2',  `status` ) >0
```